# Can't install new applications

Tags: software-installation

```
E: Could not get lock `var/lib/dpkg/lock`

 - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (`/var/lib/dpkg/`)
```

Is another process using it?